# Specific entropy of dry air formula?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, entropy

I work with one old report and I need to convert their calculations to the **SI units**. They calculate the specific entropy of the dry air there this way:
[image]

So I need to decide what to use instead of R and T there.

But actually I cannot find the same formula in other literature so far.

When I use

Cpa = 1006 J/kg,K , R = 287.058 J/kg/K and T = 298.15 K

I get the 4055.3946 J/kg/K while I expect the 5260.9616 J/kg/K

(converted from 1.2574 BTU/lbm*R)

They use these constants there:
[image]

Comment: What do you get if you use the Cp and R in SI units, but T and $\rho$ in Imperial units?

Comment: Good idea, I get 5274.1292. But where to find the SI formula ? :-)

Comment: The SI formula is going to be offset by a constant from the Imperial formula at all conditions.  This is because the entropy is a relative quantity, and the temperature and density should really be a temperature ratio and a density ratio.  As the equation stands, neither set of units calculates an absolute entropy.

Comment: Then what about this Imperial formula - is it wrong or gives the offset from some point? If it gives the offset then what is the starting point there?

Comment: Choose an initial state, and I'll show you how it works.  Please understand however, that it doesn't matter if you are only interested in determining changes in entropy.  Either way, for the change in entropy, you will get the right answer.

Comment: The formula is used to compare the entropy in different states so perhaps it works right. My concern here is that it looks weird, I do not see it in literature, cannot explain, etc.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose we chose an arbitrary reference state of $T_{ref}=0\ C = 273 \ K = 492 \ R$ and $P_{ref}=1\ atm=101325\ Pa$ and expressed the entropy equation in a little different form:  $$s_a=s_{ref}+(C_{pa}-R)\ln{(T/T_{ref})}-R\ln{(\rho_a/\rho_{a, ref})}$$where $$\rho_{ref}=\frac{P_{ref}M}{RT_{ref}}=\frac{(1)(29)}{(0.7302)(273)}=0.1455\ \frac{lb_m}{ft^3}$$ and $$s_{ref}=1.1943\ \frac{BTU}{lb_m,R}$$
If you use this equation, you will find that you get exactly the same results as you did using your original equation.  However, now, what do you get when you convert this equation to SI units and calculate the entropy?

ADDENDUM

In thermodynamics class, we learned that entropy is not usually treated as an absolute quantity, but rather a quantity that varies relative to some reference state of our choosing.  We also learned that, for an ideal gas, the change in entropy relative to our chosen reference state is expressible as:
$$s_a-s_{ref}=(C_{pa}-R)\ln{(T/T_{ref})}-R\ln{(\rho_a/\rho_{a, ref})}$$Note that, in the logarithmic terms, there are dimensionless ratios so that the units in the ratios cancel out.

Now, the question is, "What reference state did the authors of your old report choose in their equation for the entropy of the dry air?"  Well, the answer to this question is obviously the following:
$$T_{ref}=1\ degree\ R$$
$$\rho_{ref}=1\ \frac{lb_m}{ft^3}$$
And, for this choice of reference state, they specified that the entropy $s_{ref}=0\ \frac{BTU}{lb_m,R}$.  See what you get if you convert to SI units with this choice.

Comment: Yes, with your formula I get what I expect -  5262.35879 J/Kg*K  . So I can use your formula instead of theirs. But where does the s_ref come from? And if their formula is also right then here should be some way to convert your formula into theirs. How did they get rid of the reference constants in this case ?

Comment: See the ADDENDUM to my answer.

Comment: When they calculate the total entropy they add also the entropy of water vapor taken from the "steam tables". Does it mean that that tables should use the same reference state?

Comment: That's not necessary since, in all cases, only changes in entropy will be employed in calculations (so the reference state parameters will drop out).

Comment: I found several formulas for entropy but there is no such thing as (Cpa - R), usually only Cpa  Also you see, for different states the air and vapor can be in different proportions, so if the reference point is different then there will be errors, I think.

Comment: Oh, now I see that Cpa-R is simply Cva,

Comment: Yes.  And regarding your other issue, the air and the vapor make separate (summed) contributions to the total entropy.  So their being in different proportions doesn't matter as long as, when there is phase change of the water, the liquid water is also included (based also on the reference state of water).

Comment: Your reference point, sref=1.1943 - did you choose it to fit the report or it is calculated somehow?

Comment: In the first reference state I chose, $$s_{ref}=(C_p-R)\ln{492}-R\ln{0.1455}=1.1943$$

Comment: I think the version in Addenum about 1 R and 1 lbm/ft3 is the most realistic. They simply ignored sref because it anyway disappears when they later calculate the difference of two entropy values. And this approach works with SI units and constants.

Comment: Both reference state approaches are entirely equivalent, and will deliver identical results.  So, if the aesthetics of the Addendum version pleases you more, that's fine.